# Effects of Material Near PCB Coplanar Waveguide

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, rf, transmission-line

I'm designing a UHF (430 MHz) RF PCB that will use coplanar transmission lines. All of the calculators online assume a PCB substrate with air above it. But if we have an enclosure surrounding the PCB, we won't have an infinite amount of air above the board but will instead have a metal sheet near the board which could significantly impact the impedance characteristics of the trace. I would imagine that it's a function of the spacing between the driven stripline and the coplanar ground planes, but I wanted to get an accurate answer so I could size the enclosure appropriately while making it as small as possible.

Are there any good resources that talk about the effects of other materials near the coplanar lines? Are there rules of thumb on how far from the coplanar transmission lines other materials/parts/enclosures should be placed to ensure the microstrips behave as close as possible to the ideal case? Would this problem typically need to be solved in an EM program to get an accurate answer for RF layouts?

Comment: What you're describing can be modeled as a stripline.  Try using a stackup tool to see what the effects are of moving the top reference layer far away from the signal traces.